# What is the meaning of this keyring-related error?

Tags: 12.04, password, keyrings, gnome-keyring

It has been a while now since it all started and I'm not sure what cause The window in the image bellow keeps popping up from time to time and I don't know what to do about it, what could cause it and what it is its meaning.

But I can tell that I have noticed it appears especially at start up, when I use terminal, when I use Ubuntu One and when I wont to update software. Usually, I ignore it, but I still don't know what should I do: should I log into what ever that may be, or should I ignore it? And anyhow, what should I make it stop appearing? (I can recall finding somewhere a "solution" for my problem : simply erase a certain file. I have tried and it worked, but I was afraid to do a permanent change thinking that, who knows? Maybe in the future I'll need that file and then, what will I do?

Bellow you can see the window I am talking about.

[image: "Enter password to unlock your login keyring" error window]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what kind of set up of your Ubunutu you have but, whenever I have that keyring popping up on my system, usually (one of reasons) is because I configured my system to auto-login going straight to desktop from booting.  It's one of the security feature.  I have gotten used to it, and it also have prevented me from few horror errors that I was so glad I didn't disable keyring.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I don't remember configuring anything like this, but if I remember well, all this started after I uninstalled and then reinstalled PlayOnLinux. (I was not very pleased with its behaviour after a software update, so I said that it would not hurt to unistall/install PlayOnLinux from terminal, just to get accustomed wit it). Maybe the security feature has something to do with that. Anyway, what advice can you give me? How can I control this feature - and set the highest security level - without being popped out all the time? I am a newbie in Linux.

Comment: Starting from your answer, I could search deeper about this subject. Till now, I could not find a proper and not risky solution to the bugging pop ups of this window, but, the main point is that I am not worried anymore about of what I have thought to be an error. An your reply helped me to get read of those worries. Thanks!

Comment: Furthermore, after reviewing my entries on StackExchange, and came across to this.  I might should point that another reason for keyring is because I also have ssh access to my other servers on my local network system.  When I have specifically set my system to remember my passwords for these servers, hence Ubunutu uses keyring to verify that I am the very same owner, but only once and will repeat every time I boot the system.